# What is <customErrors mode="Off" /> for?

Tags: asp.net

What is this for?

ASP.NET error suggested that I have to put this in my web.config file. What do these lines of codes do?

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about `<customErrors>` element [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Specifically:

> Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors
>   are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

Answer (score 2):

### Custom Error

> To customize the default error page, one will have to change the default configuration settings of the application

There are three error modes in which an ASP.NET application can work:

- Off Mode
- On Mode
- RemoteOnly Mode

> The Error mode attribute determines whether or not an ASP.NET error message is displayed. By default, the mode value is set to "RemoteOnly".

---

### **Off Mode**

When the error attribute is set to "Off", ASP.NET uses its default error page for both local and remote users in case of an error.

---

### **On Mode**

In case of "On" Mode, ASP.NET uses user-defined custom error page instead of its default error page for both local and remote users. If a custom error page is not specified, ASP.NET shows the error page describing how to enable remote viewing of errors.

---

### **RemoteOnly**

ASP.NET error page is shown only to local users. Remote requests will first check the configuration settings for the custom error page or finally show an IIS error.

---

[More Details and referred from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2345/Custom-Errors-in-ASP-NET)   and [this MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)